# Escaping reference look-alikes in the replacement parameter of PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, reference, escaping, preg-replace

I would like to replace a pattern string '/r/' within a subject string 'r r' with predetermined replacements like '"\\23"' and '[4]'.
So (showing you only a subset of my replacements array) I try:

```
$subject = 'r r';
$replacements = array('"\\23"', '[4]');
$replacements = array_map('preg_quote', $replacements);
print_r($replacements);

foreach($replacements as $replacement){
    $subject = preg_replace('/r/', $replacement, $subject, 1);
}

echo $subject;
```

The string I want is '"\\23" [4]', 
but I get back '"\23" \[4\]', which is both missing characters and has additional characters.

Does PHP have an escape function that would work here?  How do I do this?

**Note:** Without the preg_quote line the result  is '"" [4]'.

Answer (score 0):

preg_quote function is needed only for first argument of preg_replace if it should be escaped, so remove it

to replace `r` with `"\\23"` you need to use:

```
$subject = 'r r';
$replacements = array('"\\\\23"', '[4]'); // here is double escaping, but only in code, for input you do no need to escape anyhitng
foreach ($replacements as $replacement)
    $subject = preg_replace('/r/', addcslashes($replacement, '\\'), $subject, 1); // here is the addition of \ only to \, as it is required by preg_replace
echo $subject;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

> To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled ("\\\\" PHP string).

Comment: How do I convert \\23 to \\\\23?  \\23 is an input.

Comment: @zylstra you do not need convert input, \ escaping needed only when you write string literal in code

Comment: @zylstra fixed in problem, I forgot that for preg_replace you need 4 slashes for single

Comment: Not sure what you mean by old/new.  It works for me.

Comment: @zylstra check update, as it easier to show code, instead of commenting

Comment: You say I don't need to convert input, yet you say use \\\\\\\\23 when my input is \\23.  I'd say those two strings are different.

Comment: @zylstra my fault, forget about double encoding, check update

Comment: **"\\23" IS AN INPUT.**
I am asking you to use "\\23" in your code, NOT "\\\\23".

Comment: @zylstra check my comments in code, they are answer to your question. note - there is no such thing as input in php